# I have a code that reads git log returning the error below

Tags: bash, git, shell

Error message: "fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet"

After Making a file with this code executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$BASH_SOURCE")")/.."
{
    cat <<- 'EOH'
       
    EOH
    echo
    git log --format='%aN <%aE>' | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort -uf
 } > AUTHORS
```

Comment: Well, did you have committed anything?

Comment: The `git log` command you used lists the commits on the current branch. There are no commits on the current branch, so it lists nothing (and produces the error that you saw). If you just want to discard the error, send the standard-error output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: thanks but, well if I use * 2>/dev/null *I get rid of the error but it doesn't help with the objective of the code which is to get a list of the Authors to write them to a file named Authors.. I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the code.. As when I just type git log there is definitely multiple commits

Comment: The error message indicates that you're in a repository in which you are on branch `master`, and there are no commits and the branch itself does not yet exist (is an "orphan" or "unborn" branch). If `git log` works, and shows some commits, from your shell prompt, but not from this script, these two `git log` commands must be working on/in *different Git repositories* and the next step is to figure out why *that* is the case. The `cd` at the top of the script looks suspicious, since it moves the *current directory*, which is how Git finds the repository. How are you calling this script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't add anything, and possibly didn't even have a change to commit, so no commit was done. If you really want that first commit without any changes, you can do this:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "first commit"
```

Comment: even after  inserting the above code  the error still persists